# Insert into database

Tags: sql, join, insert

I have a database with 3 tables:

```
Orders(OrderId, OrderDate, OrderValue)
OrderDetails(DetailsId, OrderId, ProductId, Quantity)
Products(ProductId, ProductName, Price)
```

I need to insert another row in Orders.

I know the `OrderId`, the `Date` but I want to calculate the `OrderValue`.

I don't know how to do it: the OrderValue will be something like that.

`(quantity*price)` where `OrderDetails.ProductId=Products.ProductId` for each row in `OrderDetails` where `OrderDetails.OrderId=Orders.OrderId`

Comment: you can try it with an insert with subquerry. insert into orders (orderid, orderdate, ordervalue) (select "orderid which you know", "date which you konw" d.quantity*p.price from orders o join orderdetails d on o.oerderid=d.orderid join prducts p on d.productid=p.prductid).

Comment: You created [an earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23558064/how-to-insert-sql) asking more or less the same thing. Next time, please edit and improve your previous question instead of asking a new one (this also prevents a question ban).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is using [View](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms187956.aspx) insted of computing OrderValue, because you should update this field every time when `Quantity` or `Price` are changed. This is not good and it contradicts 3NF also you will have a lot of other promlems. I strongly recommend to you change database structure, but if you would not change you can use following example:

```
insert into Orders(OrderId, OrderDate, OrderValue)
values(@SomeOrderID,getdate(), 0) 

insert into Products(ProductId, ProductName, Price)
values(/*some values*/)

insert into OrderDetails(DetailsId, OrderId, ProductId, Quantity)
values(/*some values, include @SomeOrderID*/)

update o set OrderValue = (p.Price* pd.Quantity)
from Orders o
inner join OrderDetails pd on pd.OrderId = o.OrderId
inner join Products p on p.ProductId = pd.ProductId 
where o.OrderId= @SomeOrderID
```

Comment: this code it works, but it calculates the OrderValue only for first row in OrderDetails....if i have more products on the same order it gives me the value only for the first one....i think i need a sum or something!

Comment: It calculates OrderValue for all OrderDetails that connected to Products. if many orders have the same orderId they are all will involve in calculation OrderValue.

Comment: i don't think u understand, or maybe i don't understand....for example...in products if i have this values: Id=1....Name=productA....Price=2, Id=2....Name=productB....Price=3, and if in OrderDetails i have....DetailsId=1  OrderId=1 ProductId=1 Quantity=2 and the second row: DetailsId=2 OrderId=1 ProductId=2 Quantity = 4......I need to insert in Orders this values: OrderId=1, GETDATE(), OrderValue (wich in this case must be 16)...your code it insert only , it doesn't add the value for the second row from OrderDetails!

Comment: I change script in my answer.I thing now it is ok.

Comment: i've got it...it is SUM(p.Price* pd.Quantity)

Answer (score 0):

If this is Oracle then you can try this

```
INSERT INTO orders 
            (orderid, 
             orderdate, 
             ordervalue) 
SELECT A.orderid, 
       A.orderdate, 
       A.quantity * B.price 
FROM   orderdetails A 
       inner join products B 
               ON A.productid = c.productid;
```